# How to show the full path and filename in OpenFileDialog

Tags: c#, winforms, openfiledialog

I'm using openfiledialog to open the file calender.txt, when it opens it displays calender as the filename and .txt in the filter box without the directory c:\

Can anyone please show me how to code the dialog so that i get C:\calender in the dialog

```
private void openFileButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
     ofd.InitialDirectory = (@"C:\");
     ofd.Filter = ("*.txt| Text File");
     ofd.FileName = "calender.txt";
     ofd.CheckFileExists = false;

     if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
     {
        if (CheckValidity(ofd.FileName))
        {
            try
            {
                streamWriter sw = new streamWriter(ofd.FileName);
            }
            catch (FileLoadException flEx)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(flEx.Message);
            }
            else
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try `ofd.FileName = Path.Combine(ofd.InitialDirectory, "calendar.txt");`?

Comment: I believe you have to set that under Folders option in control panel

Comment: Thanks TyCobb that sorted it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can set the file name to be whatever you like in the dialog. If you want to show the full path at the start, you can do the following:

```
OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
ofd.InitialDirectory = (@"C:\");
ofd.FileName = Path.Combine(ofd.InitialDirectory, "calendar.txt");
```

Keep in mind that this won't stay like this once a user selects a different file, but it won't actually matter to you because once they hit `Open`, `FileName` will have the full path for you.

Answer (score 0):

you can take the path selected by the user with

```
string path_selected = ofd.FileName;
```

for example "c://users/user/desktop/myfile.txt"

I dont know any method that returns the file name but you can use string methods to edit the path and get the file name